# How to construct delta plots for RTs

Tags: r, plot, mean

I have a dataframe **d** with reaction times (RTs) of 4 different groups:

```
NC      NI      RC      RI
574.3   1238.9  1074.8  1258.2
508.7   492.2   537.8   1105.6
680.8   457.9   439.9   609
433.7   491.2   427.3   567.1
432     474.6   481.1   503.2
470.5   442.7   510.5   503.8
419.6   501.5   412.8   445.3
557.7   464.9   550.9   458.1
445.8   498.3   411.2   495.6
```

I calculated the means for each group:

```
mean(d$NC)
mean(d$NI)
mean(d$RC)
mean(d$RI)
```

I tried to construct delta plots for RTs using the package **deltaPlotR**:

```
 deltaPlot(d, type = "response", group, focal.name, thr = "norm", 
      purify = FALSE, purType = "IPP1", maxIter = 10, alpha =0.05, 
      extreme = "constraint", const.range = c(0.001, 0.999), nrAdd = 1, 
      save.output = FALSE,output = c("out", "default"))
```

But the thing is that my variables are not dichotomous, so it doesn't work.

I also tried to use another package **ape** that also has delta plot in it:

```
delta.plot(d, k = 20, plot = TRUE, which = 1:2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: In deltaPlot: Error in internalDelta() : object 'group' not found. In delta.plot: 
Error in if (n < 4) stop("need at least 4 observations") : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: can you provide an example or a description of what you mean as "delta plot"?

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/27644037?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Too long to read, sorry. Can you provide the essence? From the glimpse at the paper you refer, the plots show the difference between two groups split by quantiles of dependent variable. Is that so?

Comment: yes, indeed. as far as I understand I need ti use quantile functions to estimate the delta plot. and only then apply one of the functions...

Comment: so you want differences between each pair of the groups? for 4 groups it will yield 6 lines, is that what you want?

Comment: also, should the quantiles represent quantiles of RT among all groups, or only the two groups for which the difference is computed? depending on that you'll have different plots

Comment: indeed, each pair of the groups. basically, I want to plot a graphical representation that displays the temporal dynamics of the RTs difference between each pair of the groups as a function of response speed (e.g., compare slow responses of one group with slow responses of another group, fast responses of one group with fast responses of another group) . I think it's better to have the quantiles of RTs for the groups for which the difference is computed

Answer (score 3):

So basically what you need is a plot of means of differences split by quantiles. The deltaPlotR is doing completely different stuff, so probably you don't need it.

I'm still not sure I clearly understand the specifics, but here's my guess:

> data<-data.table(read.table(text=readClipboard(), head=T))

(I'm reading from clipboard, you'll probably have your data in data.frame)

First you melt the data from wide to long format

> data<-melt(data)

Then for each group you create ranks based on quantiles:

> data[,quant:=as.numeric(cut(value, breaks=quantile(value,seq(0,1,.25)), include.lowest=TRUE)),by=variable]

Then you compute differences between means for each quantile:

> delta<-data[,list(delta_N=mean(ifelse(variable=='NI',value, NA), na.rm=T)-mean(ifelse(variable=='NC',value, NA), na.rm=T), delta_R=mean(ifelse(variable=='RI',value, NA), na.rm=T)-mean(ifelse(variable=='RC',value, NA), na.rm=T)),keyby=quant]

And then you plot them:

> plot(delta[,range(quant)], delta[,range(delta_N, delta_R)], type="n")
>   lines(x=delta$quant, y=delta$delta_R, ty='b', col='red') 
>   lines(x=delta$quant, y=delta$delta_N, ty='b', col='blue')

You'll have this plot:
[image]

You'll probably need to triple check the logic of computations to fit your needs. But then you need to be really sure on what you want to show on that plot.

Comment: thanks! although I am getting an error  unused argument (by = variable) when I try to create ranks based on quantiles. As far as I understand imy version of R doesn't support this function, right?

Comment: No, probably it's because you need to convert your data.frame to data.table as I do in the first piece of code

Comment: I've tried to install package CRAN that is needed for `data.table` function but I couldn't manage to install it because I have R version 3.2.2. I've tried this `install.packages("data.table", type="source")` and this `library(devtools)`; `install_github('Rdatatable/data.table')` but it didn't work either . Is there any alternative to solve this problem?

Comment: I also have R 3.2.2 and I had no problems with data.table. What's the error msg when you try to install it? The installation instructions for the most up-to-date version are here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation
But the usual install.packages('data.table') should work fine.